# What can "ranges" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, translation

"The castle’s three gift shops sell a wide range of high quality gifts, books and souvenirs including exclusive **Edinburgh Castle ranges**"

I need to translate a travel guide of the Edinburgh Castle. This guide is written in English and I need to translate it into Spanish.

I am trying to find the meaning of "ranges" in that context. However, I can only find the meaning of the verbo "to range". The meanings I find for this noun do not work in that context.

Can anyone explain to me what does "ranges" mean in that context? If anyone has a proposed translation it will be really helpful.

I really appreciate your help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the same as the first *range* in the sentence - a group of things of the same general type. The shops sell a wide range/selection/variety of gifts, of which some types are sold *only* at the Castle.

Answer (score 1):

> "The castle’s three gift shops sell a wide range of high quality
> gifts, books and souvenirs including exclusive Edinburgh Castle
> ranges"

This says that within the wide range, there are several narrower ranges!  It's not very well written.

**Possible alternative**

"The castle’s three gift shops sell a wide selection of high quality gifts, books and souvenirs including exclusive Edinburgh Castle ranges."

---

**Note**

We can only speak about English on this forum. If you want to check a translation or meaning, a better place to ask might be such as https://forum.wordreference.com/